# Issue with CTF commands 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a series of working commands that test when the player breaks the wool block (i.e. the flag), they get tagged as the `FlagCarrier`. They will also have other effects applied, specifically the glowing effect and a banner placed on their head. I know how to do the glowing and banner, but for some reason I can't seem to get the 'FlagCarrier' commands to work.

I was originally trying to `testfor` when a player breaks a certain block (at exact coordinates) I tried testing for air (which worked) - but how does the command know who broke it? So now instead I'm trying to tag whoever picks it up and has the wool block in their inventory. But I can't seem to:

```
/execute @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]} /scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1.
```

For some reason execute doesn't work with scoreboard?

My original set-up commands are:

```
/execute @a[r=100] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard objectives add FlagCarrier dummy
```

This has a comparator leading into a block with a redstone torch, so it activates when the player is NOT within 100 blocks: `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard objectives remove FlagCarrier`

`/execute @a[r=100] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar FlagCarrier` (also, this isn't showing unless I manually set it to either 1 or 0)

Also, how can I replace the block if there is no player tagged `FlagCarrier`, and no flag item on the ground? I would like to have it so a player on the blue team cannot pick up the blue flag, and it is instead returned to their base. whereas a red player could pick up the dropped flag and gain the tags.

I'm playing version 1.12, so any of the new or changed commands from 1.13+ won't help.

Comment: Your first command, `/execute @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]} /scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1` doesn't have tildes? Shouldn't it be `/execute @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]} ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1`?

Comment: Your commands seem to be a mix of 1.12 commands and 1.13 command, I recommend reading or watching a commands tutorial that came out after 1.13 or an update video that summarises the changes, for example this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO41sptfGt8 But the existing answer is already good, checking the pickup and drop directly is better.

Comment: Related: [How can I detect if a player has a specific item with a specific datavalue in their inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196677/how-can-i-detect-if-a-player-has-a-specific-item-with-a-specific-datavalue-in-th)

Answer (score 4):

What you have is close, the main problem is in your execute:

```
/execute @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]} /scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1
```

What this execute is doing is running `scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1` at the position of all players for which `{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]}` matches. In other words, if one or more players have wool with damage value 11, the command block sets the FlagCarrier score for @a (every player in the server) to 1.

This can be simplified using just a `/scoreboard` command that utilizes the appropriate NBT data:

```
/scoreboard players set @a FlagCarrier 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:wool",Damage:11s}]}
```

This sets the FlagCarrier score to 1 for all players that match that NBT (aka, all players that have that particular color of wool in their inventory).

Answer (score 2):

Depends what version you're using but if you're using 1.13 or over, do this:

> First make a new objective where the objective is to pick up wool

```
/scoreboard objectives add (Name) minecraft.picked_up:minecraft.(color)_wool
```

Next set up a repeat command block that is always on that will detect who has the wool and give them glowing

```
/execute as @a[scores={(Name)=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:glowing 1 10 true
```

Next, make another objective that will see when a player drops the wool

```
/scoreboard objectives add (Name2) minecraft.dropped:minecraft.(same color as last time)_wool
```

Then make two other repeat command blocks that are always on and put this in the first

```
/execute as @a[scores={(Name2)=1}] run scoreboard players remove @s (Name) 1
```

and this in the second

```
/execute as @a[scores={Name1=1}] run scoreboard players remove @s (Name2) 1
```

Lastly, add the players to both of the scoreboards and you should be good.
Hope this helps!

Comment: As of 1.13 they completely changed commands, so I still use 1.12. Any chance you know how to do it in 1.12? I'll see if these work in 1.12, I think the only difference is Execute format. Anyways thanks, I didn't know picked_up was an objective.

Comment: @Aceplante commands have become so much easier and more powerful in 1.13 and above.  This problem actually becomes almost trivial in 1.13 as described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/337013/1351).