# Command block quandary

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a 2 player adventure map. Throughout the map there are places where both players will enter at the same time. The question I have is this: is there a way to have a command block say something to both players that only they can see (like a secret that the other one can't see)

This is going to be a big part of the game as it's a team work/PvP mystery game, so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

## Yes! There are two ways:

You can either `/tellraw` or you could `/msg`. Syntax:

```
/tellraw [selector] [json string]
/msg [selector] [message]
```

Both have arguments that allow you to specify who to send said message to.
Just have them filterable in some way, for example: Assigning teams.

Alternatively, this [really complicated and botched method also works](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192640/how-to-get-and-store-player-name/192645#192645) (though I wouldn't recommend it, at all, because you would need one set per concurrent player and does not support people switching in/out).

---

```
/scoreboard objectives add PlayerID PlayerID dummy
<insert my linked crude contraption>
/tellraw @a[score_PlayerID_min=0,score_PlayerID=0] {text:"You are player 0"}
/msg @a[score_PlayerID_min=1,score_PlayerID=1] You are player 1.
```

Comment: Further explanation about this: Wiki link to how the easiest solution works: minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/tell So to for example tell the nearest player "Start now!", the command is just "/tell @p Start now!", alternatively you can also use /w or /msg, they work the same. To tell the player called "Horst" the message "This is a text", it also works as expected: "/tell Horst This is a text". The part that we can't help you with is the selector. Either you want the nearest player, a player with a certain name, a player with a certain tag or score or something else, that depends on your map.

Comment: I should have specified, it would be 2 people I wouldn't know the name of?

Comment: The idea is that; throughout the game the players are told different things whilst working together, and one ends up trying to kill the other player, so it needs to be like a secret message

Comment: @Fabian By "further explanation", you mean "spell out the commands so that one can copy-paste without thinking ", right? Because I already started ways you can differentiate the players. Also, I don't see a [tag:minecraft-commands] tag.

Comment: @aytimothy You gave the command structure and I thought it would be helpful to have examples, so I wrote them. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Dannyyeti The easiest solution would be to put the command blocks near the locations where the players will be when you want to tell them something and just use @p as the selector. This isn't a very elegant solution, but for a more elegant solution you would have to know stuff about selectors, scoreboards, tags, /execute or something else that helps in this case. If you want to make a complex map, that's probably required anyway, but otherwise I would recommend just placing the command blocks nearby and learning about the other things when you need them or are interested.

Comment: Cheers Fabian, I'm not clued up on commands so I was just seeking help, think I'll take the easy route for now and go with the @p, I'll figure out a way to make it work maybe using books or something!

Answer (score -1):

Create the visible area somewhere and clone it as invisible bedrock area and set the visible area 100 blocks bottom the invisible area (on the example).

Then place 7 blocks as a string somewhere; set 3 slow redstone repeaters on blocks 2, 4 and 6, and place impulse command blocks on blocks 3, 5 and 7.
Program Impulse command block on block 3 by the command:`/execute <player name> ~ ~ ~ teleport @p ~ ~-100 ~`

Program the command block on the 5th block to: `/execute <player name> ~ ~ ~ teleport @p ~ ~+100 ~`

Program the command block on 7th block by: `/setblock <cordinates of the top of the first block> air`

Type to a repeating command block `/clear <player name> gold_nugget 0 1`

And then connect it to a conditional chaincommand block with command: `/setblock <cordinates of the top of the first block> redstone_block`

Set 3rd conditional chaincommand block on the chaincommand block on the repeating command block with command: `give <player name> gold_nugget 1 0`

(And remember to give yourself the gold nugget, or it will not work for you, you need to do 2 of that command block creations to allow the trick for your friend too!) 
(This example is from minecraft PE, I don't know, what version do you have, but I did what I can.)

Comment: Errr.. What are you trying to answer?